# Create json file using jquery variable

Tags: jquery, variables

Is it possible to create file in jquery using variable data?

```
        var createText = "Some text"
```

After that, I want to save test_name.txt file with data from variable "createText".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: How to store created file using jquery in tmp folder without asking (Save file as..). After some action, delete that tmp file. Is this thing possible? Tnx

Comment: to save files with javascript and / or `jQuery` is not a standard functionality. so just look at the question and the answers which i posted.